# send different response to ajax using executor service

Tags: java, ajax, executorservice

Let's say I am making an ajax call which will get a string as a response. How will I send 3 different response to same ajax call using java's executor service?

Comment: If you want to keep an open connection, so server can send multiple responses from background threads, then you should look into **Web Sockets**, not AJAX.

Answer (score 2):

You can't send 3 response in only one ajax call.
One request will always return one response.

To solve this problem,  you can make 3 request (3 ajax) OR put all your information in your unique ajax response

Comment: yeah, i think using sockets could be a solution